# How to return boolean value to function and evaluate with an if/elif check?

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, boolean-logic

```
# v1.0#
#######
import time


#Definitions#

def StartOrNah():
    print#Newline
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print("To begin, type 'start' or to exit type 'exit'...")
    time.sleep(0.6)
    sorn = str(raw_input("--> ")).lower()
    if sorn == str("start"):
        return True
    elif sorn == str("exit"):
        return False
    else:
        print#Newline
        print("That is not valid, please try again.")
        StartOrNah()

def program():
    print#Newline
    print("The main program function has been invoked.")


#Calls#
StartOrNah()
if StartOrNah:
    program()
elif StartOrNah:
    print#Newline
    print("The program will now exit...")
    time.sleep(3)
```

My goal is to return a boolean value to the StartOrNah function, and use an if check to see if the result is True or False. I've tried a few methods of this, but I can never get False to be recognized in the evaluation. I feel like I'm doing functions terribly wrong.

I'd appreciate it if answers are kept semi-simple, as I'm a bit new to the language.

Comment: Why do you keep casting strings to strings?

Comment: Please note that in Python 3 the statement `print` by itself doesn't do anything, it just evaluates the `print` function without calling it. You need to write `print()` to print a newline. In Python 2 however, you would be doing the correct thing. Since you are using `raw_input` I'm pretty sure this is actually Python 2 and so your tag is mistaken.

Comment: @AlexHall Holy hell, I thought I was using Python 3, but you're absolutely right! I thought it was acting finnicky.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 It's just a pointless habit, like commenting printed new lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's three problems and no answers seem to be covering them all properly, so here goes. In this snippet:

```
else:
    print#Newline
    print("That is not valid, please try again.")
    StartOrNah()
```

By leaving out the keyword `return`, you ensure that `StartOrNah()` will be called but its result will be lost and the caller (the original `StartOrNah`) will simply return `None` since the last statement that was executed didn't have a return. `None` will then be treated like `False` in an `if` statement. You need to prepend `return` to that last line.

To demonstrate this, run this small program:

```
def foo():
    3

print foo()

def bar():
    return 3

print bar()
```

In this snippet:

```
#Calls#
StartOrNah()
if StartOrNah:
    program()
```

when you say `if StartOrNah` you are asking if the object `StartOrNah`, **which is a function**, is equivalent to `True`, which is misguided (it always will be). Calling `StartOrNah()` returns a value that you are supposed to keep and do something with, just like you were supposed to `return` it above. It doesn't mean you are then supposed to ask what the result was by referring to the name of the function. Instead you need to do something like this:

```
result = StartOrNah()
if result:
    program()
```

To help your understanding, I recommend also adding two lines so that it looks like this:

```
result = StartOrNah()
print("result:", result)
print("StartOrNah:", StartOrNah)
if result:
    program()
```

You should see that `result` is either `True` or `False` while `StartOrNah` is a function.

Next, in this snippet:

```
if StartOrNah:
    program()
elif StartOrNah:
    print#Newline
```

if `StartOrNah` is `False` then neither block will be executed. Use `else` instead of `elif` because `elif` still requires that the condition given is true (hence the contained `if`) which obviously isn't the case since the original `if` just showed it was false. On the other hand, `else` is always executed when the matching `if` (and any `elif`s) were not executed.

Unless all of these problems are fixed I expect that the program will not work as you imagine.

Since you have some confusion about how functions work I strongly recommend staying away from recursion (i.e. calling `StartOrNah()` within `StartOrNah()`) for now since this will only make things more confusing and difficult. Play around with some simple toy programs to improve your understanding of the foundational concepts.

Comment: Write about calling functions with `()`, and also about the fact that `print` (as any other callable thing) just returns a `print` object if it's not called and I'll remove my answer and upvote yours.

Comment: @IlyaPeterov added a comment to the question about `print`.

Comment: @AlexHall Thank you! What a great answer. Can you elaborate on the `return` after the recursion of StartOrNah? I'm still confused as to what's going on there.

Comment: @Gavin I added an example.

Comment: @AlexHall I'm getting a syntax error when it comes to printing the functions

Comment: @Gavin The foo/bar one? I ran it myself and copy pasted it so that's weird. What's the error?

Comment: @AlexHall Ah, I see you were using Python 2.x. Sorry. That clarifies a bit. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you don't return a value from your recursion.  Add one word to that clause:

```
else:
    print#Newline
    print("That is not valid, please try again.")
    return StartOrNah()
```

Comment: He should always return a value; that's the purpose of the function.  The invalid clause recurs until it gets a valid response.

Answer (score 0):

I am quite an newbie too...

So if you say:

```
if StartorNah():
    pass
```

You're trying to see if it is `True`. If you want to see if it is `False` instead, use:

```
if not StartorNah():
    print#Newline
    print("The program will now exit...")
    time.sleep(3)
```

You could also use a `else` statement, which will be used if every other `if` and `elif` statements' conditions are not met:

```
else:
    print#Newline
    print("The program will now exit...")
    time.sleep(3)
```

As mentioned in the comment, try using `StartorNah()` instead of `StartorNah`.

Comment: You should call a function like that `StartOrNah()` and not like that `StartOrNah`. Writing 'StartOrNah' will just return a function object.